# How do Open Source Blockchain companies Stay Competitive?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, open-source

I understand the importance of having secure code and your customers trusting your brand. What I do not understand is how do open source blockchain companies like Wallets stay competitive when their competitors can fork their code? Also, is this standard different for closed source exchanges because they do not show source code, however some of them are not regulated.

If I was not clear, I am confused about the whole concept of "Open Sourcing" everything and building a competitive business.

Answer (score 1):

They can do this because the crypto market can support multiple companies

However, it does not happen many times anyway, due to the following reasons:

- Just "forking" is not as easy as it sounds; you also need:
- Infrastructure & dev-ops
- Support
- A legal entity
- There might be a lack of skilled people, which get hired by the companies instead of starting their own projects
- Response time: why would I use a fork, if the project it was forked from is the original one, with faster bugfixes?

In addition, some companies only open-source a limited portion of their code that does not let you run it, [which is pointless](https://github.com/Jaxx-io/Jaxx/issues/6#issuecomment-307751196), the way I see it.